# Determining if one string contains another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string, `'|lcol~-1|lcol~-1'`. I need to determine if the string contains `'-1'` using JavaScript. How can I achieve this without using the `indexOf` method?

Comment: " i dont want to use index of method"   Why???

Comment: *"i dont want to use index of method"* Why in heaven's name not?

Comment: please read faq and post question

Comment: Sounds like a trolling: "I want to achive this on Javascript but I don't want to use Javascript"...

Comment: coz sometimes indexof gives -1 eventhough it doesnot matches a string like suppose u are finding '-1' in an empty string......Can we overwrite the contains method or is there any other method rather than indexof

Comment: Can you post an example of string for which indexOf doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, you *can* do it other ways, such as:

```
if (str.split("-1").length > 1) {
   // Yes, `str` has "-1" in it
}
```

or

```
if (/-1/.exec(str)) {
    // Yes, `str` has "-1" in it
}
```

But `indexOf` really would be the most direct, straightforward, and maintainable way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use indexOf().
But you could try this too:

```
if(mystring.replace('-1','') != mystring) {...}
```